# How can we manage the front-end projects dependency packages like Maven in IDEA

Tags: maven, npm, webstorm, dependency-management

There are more and more front-end projects, and each project has its own `node_modules` folder.

There are a lot of duplicate files in the modules folder.

How can we manage the dependency packages of all front-end projects in one folder like Maven in IDEA?

Demand：

1. When running and packaging different projects, WebStorm can refer to the dependent packages in a specified folder.
2. When run `npm install`, computer will check whether the public dependency package folder has the dependency version that the current project needs to use.

   - If so, you will not download the installation.
   - If not, you will download your own dependency to the public folder.
3. When multiple versions exist in the same dependent package, the project can automatically reference the correct version.

Maybe after reading my question, you know my actual needs better than I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the `package.json` file in any front-end project with **npm** you will see all the dependencies in the current project and can manage the versions there. `npm install` installs the **dependencies** listed in that file.

Read more about `package.json` here: [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json)

Comment: Thank you very much.     I changed it angular.json Inside "$schema": ".. / node_ modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/ schema.json ",     Completed multiple projects to share a node_modules folder. However, there are two problems

1. When NPM install is executed in the project, NPM will be in the node of the current project_ Modules folder, according to the package.json Install all dependencies.    2. The tslint of the current project can't find the TS dependent package, and always prompt: 'install the tslint package'

Answer (score 0):

Using the yarn workspace

Yarn workspace features, and solves

1. multiple projects repeat node in large quantities_ Black hole problem of modules disk
2. when NPM install is executed for a project, all dependent packages will be placed in the node of the project in the current project_ Install it again under the modules folder

   2.1 when installing a new dependency package, you should update the package.json of the subproject, and then execute the yarn install in the root directory to install it

Install the yarn tool first

npm i yarn -g

If there are projects project-a and project-b in the root folder, the directory structure is as follows:

```
root

project-a

project-b
```

1. create package.json in the root folder, with the following contents:

```
{

"private": true,

"workspaces": ["project-a", "project-b"]

}
```

2. ensure that the name attribute values in the package.json of project-a and project-b projects are:

```
Package.json in project-a:

{

...

"name": "project-a"

...

}

Package.json in project-b:

{

...

"name": "project-b"

...

}
```

3. use the command line tool to enter the root folder and execute the yarn install

   ```
    3.1 after installation, you can enter the normal start-up project
   ```
4. tips:

   ```
    4.1 all dependent packages will be installed at root/node_ Under modules folder
    4.2 node of subproject_ The related link file will be generated under the modules folder, do not delete it
    4.3 when installing a new dependency package, you should update the package.json of the subproject, and then execute the yarn install in the root directory to install it
   ```